# SQL Data to layout (SQL 1 Column to multiple column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I need to make layout from my SQL data. So, I need SQL data one column to multiple column but column or row quantity will be variable. Any ideas please.

Example (SQL column):

```
Serial
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Need look like (if customer I want 2 column than):

```
1  6  or  1  4
2  5      2  5
3  4      3  6
```

Comment: This is 99.44% better to do after selecting the data as it is to asp and just generate the new columns

Comment: `select min(Serial), max(Serial) from (select *, count(*) over () as count from yourtable) as t group by Serial % (count / 2)` but honestly SQL is absolutely the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH NumberedRows AS (
    SELECT 
        Serial,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Serial) AS RowNumber
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
    A.Serial AS Column1,
    B.Serial AS Column2
FROM NumberedRows A
JOIN NumberedRows B ON A.RowNumber = B.RowNumber * -1 + (SELECT MAX(RowNumber) + 1 FROM NumberedRows)
WHERE A.RowNumber <= (SELECT MAX(RowNumber) FROM NumberedRows) / 2
```

This query generates pairs of rows from the Serial column in a layout that matches `(1 6, 2 5, 3 4)` by utilizing row numbers and joining the table with itself based on the row numbers assumeing the `Serial` column contains sequential numbers starting from `1`.

[See this **db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/-6FEXPj0).

Comment: Ohh! I got it. Many many thanks. Amit Mohanty.